# AngularJS : $compile not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following code, the $compile is not working.
I have an item, I am adding this item to scope, so that I can compile this and get an html.

```
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url : url

        }).success(function(response) {
            // var data = response.data;
            $scope.item = preItem ;
            var e = $compile('<div>{{item.name}}</div>')($scope);

        });
    }
```

After that, I made every thing very static and event after that this didn't worked.

```
 $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url : url

        }).success(function(response) {

            $scope.tosenddata = 'testdata';
            var e = $compile('<div>{{tosenddata}}</div>')($scope);

        });
    }
```

Even after this the result was same!

I am doing this inside a controller.

Comment: what is the in e finally?

Comment: var fullhtml = e.wrap('<div>').parent().html(); 
Tells, this is the output in e :  
"<div class="ng-binding ng-scope">{{tosenddata}}</div>"

Comment: when you compile such html which contains directives it will return compiled template, then you can append it as your wish

Comment: "when you compile such html which contains directives it will return compiled template, then you can append it as your wish"
-Sorry unable to get that! Please elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In this case $compile is working and if you console the "e" it will show the angular's div element bind with ng-scope.

Now "e" is just a angular div element you need to insert it into the DOM to see the HTML or console e[0].

```
 $scope.tosenddata = 'testdata';
 var e = $compile('<div>{{tosenddata}}</div>')($scope);
 console.log(e[0]);
```

In console you will see `<div class="ng-scope ng-binding">testdata</div>`

See console in this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pushpak4r/U3pVM/20321/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One reason that it may not working is that it not reaching $http success callback.
You should use both error & success for $http.

```
 $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: '/someUrl'
       }).then(function successCallback(response) {

       }, function errorCallback(response) {

      });
```

Rest its working see [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/20322/) here